# QML - SpinBox - how to know if it's UP or DOWN pressed

Tags: qt, qml, qspinbox, spinbox

I'm trying to create a custom `CustomSpinBox` in QML and I want to increase or decrease the value from `stepSize` based on which button is going to be pressed. For example, if I am pressing the UP button I want to increase the value by X and if I am pressing the DOWN button I want to decrease the value by Y.

I know about `up.pressed` and `down.pressed` but those are just properties, how can I get their value inside on `stepSize` function?

**CustomSpinBox.qml**

```
CustomSpinBox{
....
}
```

Usage:

```
CustomSpinBox{
    id: maximumSpeed


    maximumValue: 100
    minimumValue: 0.01
    suffix: " " + qsTr("m/s")
    decimals: 3
    value: connection && connection.maxSpeed.value > 0 ? connection.maxSpeed.value : 1.5
    enabled: idOverrideDefault.checked

    stepSize: {
        // if UP is pressed return UP_VALUE
        // if DOWN is pressed return DOWN_VALUE
    }

    onValueChanged: {
        if (connection) {
            editor.handleSpeedRestriction(idOverrideDefault.checked, value)
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Well, I have a number, for example, 1. If you will press the UP button is going to become 2, 3, 4, and so on. But If you will press the DOWN button it will become 0.9, 0.8, 0.7 .... 0.1 if you will press again the DOWN button it will become 0.09, 0.08, ... 0.01. The problem that I have is that I don't know how can I achieve something like this without knowing whether is going to go UP or DOWN.

I mean for example if my value is 1 I want that if I will press UP my stepSize to be 1, but if I will press DOWN to be 0.1
The same if my value will be 0.1, if I will press UP then my stepSize should be 0.1 but if I will press DOWN should be 0.01.

Because of this problem I need to know which button is pressed at each time.

Also if I am trying to write `maximumSpeed.up.pressed` is going to give me this error message:  `Cannot read property 'pressed' of undefined`
Also if I am going to define my property insider of `CustomSpinBox` for example something like this  `property bool isUp: root.up.pressed` then this is never going to be updated so I will always have a `false` over there.

Comment: I don't think changing `stepSize` based on which button is pressed will work. I expect that by the time you update its value, the increase/decrease functions will already have been called. Or at least, you won't be able to rely on the order of events. I think you will need to create your own buttons and manually tell them what to do when they are pressed.

Comment: is there is no way in which I can get which button was pressed inside my stepSize function?

Comment: something like that: `property var someValue: down.pressed ? -1 : (up.pressed ? 1 : 0)`?

Comment: that's a good idea except that... How do I update my property? I mean if I will say something like this it will be always `false` because it will be once initialized and never updated. How can I update this in this case?

Comment: And I couldn't find anything like `up.onPressed` or something like this

Comment: @folibis showed you how to do it: `stepSize: down.pressed ? -1 : (up.pressed ? 1 : 0)`. I just don't think it will work because of the reasons I stated above. But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I did update my question explaining why is either not working or I have no idea how to make it work.

Comment: did you try my solution?

Comment: yes, I did but is not working as I explain in my **UPDATE**. Basically, if I am trying to use something like this `root.up.pressed` where root is my CustomSpinBox ID I will get an error message such  `Cannot read property 'pressed' of undefined` (same if I am not using root and I am using directly `up`). I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but is not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use property group syntax as :

```
SpinBox
{
    property bool isUpPressed: up.pressed
    property bool isDownPresed: down.pressed

    up.onPressedChanged: {
        isUpPressed = up.pressed
    }
    down.onPressedChanged: {
        isDownPresed = down.pressed
    }
}
```

for Quick.Controls 1. where up and down are not available, this trick can be used :

```
   SpinBox
    {
        property int oldValue: -1
      
        onValueChanged: {
            if (value > oldValue)
            {
                console.log("up")
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("down")
            }
            oldValue = value
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not working, I'm getting the following error message if I am trying to add this code into my `SpinBox` item.  `Cannot assign to non-existent property "down"
        down.onPressedChanged: {`

Comment: And I am also getting the same error also for `up` not only `down`

Comment: Which qt version are you using? And how do you import your controls in qml? Can you try my answer with "import QtQuick.Controls 2.0"

Comment: Well regarding the QT version is 5.14.2 and regarding the QtQuick I am using 1.4. If would be to use 2.0 I have a problem that is not recognizing the `style` property and is getting an error  `Cannot assign to non-existent property "style"
        style: SpinBoxStyle {`

Comment: And I just found that style is not available in QtQuick.Controls 2.0.What should I do in this case?

Comment: Also, I have multiple problems if I am going to use QtQuick.Controls 2.0 as I've just checked. Do you know any possibility of how can I achieve this without using 2.0?

Comment: This is working, thanks you so much for your help :)